# What does the Axe Expertise extra feature mean by "that results in a 1"?

Tags: dnd-4e

What does the `Axe Expertise` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3122)] extra feature mean by *that results in a 1*?

> Also, when rolling damage for a weapon attack you make with an axe, you can reroll one damage die that results in a 1, but you must use the second result.

Comment: its pseudo brutal 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If any of your dice look like this, you may *pick one of them* and reroll it.**  Do not count the original roll, use whatever you rolled the second time with that die.

[image: one is bad]

Comment: gorgeous dice, are those yours?

Comment: @patludwig Blimey, what axe has a D20 **damage** dice  :-)

Comment: @waxeagle yep, got a couple sets.  I enjoy them a bunch, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the case, but the wording *"that results in a one"* got me double-thinking myself

Comment: @SteveC - I dunno, but once I had the dice out I didn't want to leave any of them out of the shot. :)  Plus there is probably some Dragon article that has a d20 axe, maybe an April's fools issue somewhere!

Comment: Uhm... so if one of my dice end up being made of gold I can reroll it? ^_^

Comment: @ErikBurigo If you gift it to the DM, it works pretty well...

Comment: As a DM myself, I totally agree.